# Matlab 2012 b with OpenCV 2.4.10

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv

I am using MATLAB 2012b with OpenCV 2.4.10. I have a function called `dicomread6_mex.cpp`. However, when I execute the MATLAB command

```
mex dicomread6_mex.cpp
```

This error appears

```
>> mex dicomread6_mex.cpp
dicomread6_mex.cpp 
dicomread6_mex.cpp(8) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp': Permission denied 

C:\PROGRA~1\MATLAB\R2012A\BIN\MEX.PL: Error: Compile of 'dicomread6_mex.cpp' failed.
```

Comment: Does the file exist? Can you open it?

Comment: Yes I can open the directory

Comment: Can you share the next generation opencv lib, please? ;D

Comment: Can you explain your question please?

Comment: It says permission denied.  Did you try running MATLAB as root (Linux / Mac OS) or administrator (Windows)?

Comment: I try with administrator mode. But, the same problems appear